# QuirksMode mouse position incorrect for SVG in a jQueryUI tab?

Tags: svg, mouseover, jquery-ui-tabs

I've just noticed something strange. If I draw an SVG shape, the co-ordinates I supply as the shape's x and y attributes don't match up with the co-ordinates returned by a mouse event on that shape, when using the standard ways of returning the mouse position.

For example, if I draw a rectangle as follows:

```
shape = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "x", rect_x);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "y", rect_y);
...
shape.addEventListener("mouseover", etc);
```

in the event routine, I get the mouse position using the QuirksMode algorithm (the "correct script for detecting the mouse co-ordinates", at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html). For the Y co-ordinate, I have to correct the QuirksMode value as follows, in order to get to 'rect_y':

```
F/F 8  subtract 105
Webkit subtract 103
IE9    subtract 104
Opera  subtract 103
```

What's also curious is that both Webkit and IE9 provide evt.offsetY, and set it to the 'correct' position (exactly equal to 'rect_y'). FF leaves offsetY undefined, and Opera sets it to 1.

I suspect that the issue is that this is in a jQueryUI tab, although I haven't worked this through yet. Anyone seen this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In SVG you would use the getScreenCTM method to convert co-ordinates rather than offsetX or offsetY etc. There's an example here: http://www.carto.net/svg/eventhandling/ Search for the Converting clientX to viewBox coordinates part. It's a bit complicated as it tries to cope with old UAs such as ASV3 that don't have a getScreenCTM method.